# Sendig a GET request to REST API from phone app

Tags: android, cordova, get

I have an app that I made using Apache Cordova (it turns HTML/CSS/JS websites into an app, basically). It sends a simple GET request to my REST API that is running locally on a PC. I'm using the local (not localhost) IP of the PC (192.168.x.x) and the right port, but it doesn't seem to work. However, I am able to do it "manually" through the browser on my phone by typing in the address and port.
`<uses-permission name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` is already in the .xml file. my Firewall is deactivated and my network is set to "private network".

EDIT 20.3.2020 13:08: I realized I was looking at the wrong .xml file, but the problem still persists. Adding the whole config.xml file for clarity.

`<xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <feature name="Whitelist">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <uses-permission name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

    `<name></name>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*"/>
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
</widget>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the following entry to you config.xml so GET requests are allowed

```
<access origin="192.168.x.x" />
```

Comment: What does the chrome debugger tell you if you try to request?

Comment: I think you don't understand what the problem is. The request should be sent from the app (the phone)  to the computer.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. You can debug the Android webview content using the Chrome debug tools. Look [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/9.x/guide/next/index.html#chrome-remote-debugging) for more details.

Comment: It seems that cleartext was disabled, hence why it didn't work. Thank you very much!